# blurring a web page in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

i have a web page that has to go dim on page load and some box comes over.
  the box has to have a TextBox. this box takes some input from the user. and on click
  on a submit button the TextBox info is **to be checked on server** and then accordingly the 
  already dimmed web page may go normal(usable) or keep dimmed.

**very much like what happens on opening the home page of www.sulekha.com**

please guide me on this.

thankQ

Comment: I don't see any of the effect upon opening that page.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using the ChildWindow in the Silverlight Toolkit, does that not give you the intended "modal" + "grey out background" behaviour

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%204

Sample here:
http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html